# Adobe CQ Integration with Open AM

Tags: session, authentication, adobe, aem

We plan to create Login functionality in Web Portal.
The login page as simple jsp file rests on top of Open AM Web Server.
The user enters login credentials in this login page.
There is an authentication with Open AM and Open DJ directory.
After authentication, we need the user to be redirected to Adobe CQ Web Portal.

Here, we would like to establish User Session with Adobe CQ.
Any page requests will have to be intercepted with Session handling.
How do we handle this functionality in Adobe CQ.

There is functionality of idle timeout and Session timeout.
How do we handle this in Adobe CQ ?

We are quite confused with Day CQ Login Handler, Sling Authentication, SAML Authentication Osgi bundles wtc

Appreciate if any could help us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate SAML with AEM. Please see this detail steps [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/saml-demo.html)